# data loader every time showing 0 successful

Tags: data-loader

Hi I export a report from production, now I want to move exported report to sandbox object. In my report contain all fields same in that sandbox object. But every time it shows 0 successful and 103 errors. I am using data loader for this,

i have total 103 records in my report. in the csv error report

> "Required fields are missing: [Account__c]"

Comment: what error are you getting in the error file?

Comment: i have total 103 records in my report. in the csv error report  "Required fields are missing: [Account__c]"

Comment: Well isn't it clear from the error that the Account__c values are missing? Maybe you did some changes in the Sandbox by making that field mandatory, or added this new field perhaps. But this should be something really simple for you to identify and fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a new sandbox that you are loading data into then and the object looks up to the Account object, you'll need to first load the Account records into the sandbox. The best way to do this is to export the account records from the source sandbox (including the ID) and then load those records into the new sandbox. The success file will now have a record with the source sandbox ID and the destination sandbox ID. You'll need to replace the Account__c field in the new object file with the new account ids. Vlookup can do this easily.

If your accounts look up to other objects then you'll need to load those first and replace those IDs in your account file as well. It's not a fun process but it's all doable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update lookup field values to relevant Sandbox values before updating them in Sandbox? If not, please update the lookup field values to relevant values in Sandbox before executing the data load.

Comment: i dont have any records in sandbox. and this new sandbox i created from production.

Answer (score 0):

Map the Account__C field from the csv's column. From the error message it seems that this custom field is compulsory field which you are not mapping, hence you are hitting the error.

Please let me know if you need more information here.

Regards,
Krishna

Comment: in my account__c have look up field, how to map that field?

Comment: @Rajesh just grab the Id and add into your csv file. then perform operation.

Comment: can you explain that records in sandbox and production are with same Id or different. if yes then you can populate this id's in csv and map to Account__c field.